# Lua - how do storyboard scenes transition to composer scenes?

Tags: lua, storyboard, composer-php

My storyboard scenes transition to each other and so do my composer scenes. But when I want a storyboard scene to transition to a composer scene the screen goes dark and things stop dead.
Scene one - storyboard:

```
     ---------------------------------------- 
     -- firstBar1.lua
     ----------------------------------------

    local storyboard = require "storyboard"
    local scene = storyboard.newScene()

    function scene:createScene(event) 
    local screenGroup = self.view

    local widget = require "widget"

    local function onFirstBar2BtnRelease()
            storyboard.gotoScene("firstBar2", "fade", 40)
            return true     
    end

    image1 = "images/staveBlankgrey2.png" -- the only button necessary

    local firstBar2Btn = widget.newButton{
            defaultFile = image1,
            width = 480, height = 320,
            onRelease = onFirstBar2BtnRelease
    } 

            screenGroup:insert(firstBar2Btn) 

   -- clef24

    image2 = display.newImageRect("images/clef24C.png", 100, 118)
    image2.x = display.contentWidth
    image2.y = display.contentHeight
    image2.x, image2.y = 62, 149

    screenGroup:insert(image2)

     -- workout count

    image3 = display.newImageRect("images/ex1of4.png", 60, 30)
    image3.x = display.contentWidth
    image3.y = display.contentHeight
    image3.x, image3.y = 32, 20

    screenGroup:insert(image3)

     -- note1

    image4 = display.newImageRect("images/crUp.png", 40, 75)
    image4.x = display.contentWidth
    image4.y = display.contentHeight
    image4.x, image4.y = 170, 167
    screenGroup:insert(image4)

     -- note2

    image5 = display.newImageRect("images/crDown.png", 40, 75)
    image5.x = display.contentWidth
    image5.y = display.contentHeight
    image5.x, image5.y = 320, 142

    screenGroup:insert(image5)

    end

    scene:addEventListener("createScene", scene)

    return scene
```

Second scene - composer:

```
     -----------------------------------------------
     -- firstBar2.lua
     -----------------------------------------------

    local composer = require ( "composer" )
    local scene = composer.newScene()

            local function showEvenBars()
                    local options = {
                            effect = "slideLeft",
                            time = 30,
                    }
            composer.gotoScene( "evenBars", options )
            end

     -- create scene

    function scene:createScene ( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    end
```

The code works up to here.

```
    function scene:show( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

            if ( phase == "will") then
                    local background = display.newImage("images/staveBlankgrey2.png", 240, 160)
                    note1 =  display.newImage( "images/crUp.png", 130, 187)
                    note2 =  display.newImage( "images/crUp.png", 320, 187)

                    sceneGroup:insert( background )
                    sceneGroup:insert( note1 )
                    sceneGroup:insert( note2 )

            elseif ( phase == "did") then                                                   
                timer.performWithDelay(tempo, showEvenBars)
            end
    end

    function scene:hide( event )
          local sceneGroup = self.view
          local phase = event.phase
    end

    function scene:destroy( event )
          local sceneGroup = self.view
    end

    scene:addEventListener( "create", scene)
    scene:addEventListener( "show", scene)
    scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene)
    scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene)

    return scene
```

This second scene, firstBar2 lua doesn't come on screen.
I'd be very grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to switch between storyboard and composer scene because they two are different libraries so their structure is different.

If you want your app to run properly you must always use one scene manager.

I recommend Composer.

Comment: Thanks, that's important to know. I've been searching for the composer version of buttons in order to change from storyboard but I'm having trouble finding examples of code. I tried substituting 'composer' for 'storyboard' in the initial set up but that didn't work. Where should I look?

Comment: Corona composer library is almost similar to storyboard .

Comment: You should look the documentation. You will find the basic setup there

Comment: https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/api/library/composer/index.html you can get it here....let me know if you have any other problems

Comment: Thanks. The changes needed were very small.

Comment: Yeah and composer is cooler!  You can use composer GUI to create levels of your game and add physics without coding. Just you have to code the behaviours and add listeners. Composer GUI is only available for Mac.

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry to persist - any ideas how I can put a button into firstBar2 above so it stops and goes back to firstBar1 yet continues to time out if the button isn't pressed? I've been trying for hours but can't make progress.

Comment: Make it a separate question along with your code. I will surely help you. Add corona as a tag.